# $f(x)$ be the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ ; then is it true that $f(1)=1+\operatorname{trace}(A)+O(\|A\|^2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, soft-question, normed-spaces

Let $f(x)$ be the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$; then is it true that $f(1)=1+\operatorname{trace}(A)+O(\|A\|^2)$ ?   I need a proof if it is true ; or any modification that is true .  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Almost: you got a sign wrong.  Consider expanding the Leibniz formula for the determinant $\det(\lambda I - A)$ (which is either $f(\lambda)$ or $(-1)^n f(\lambda)$ depending on your convention).  The coefficient of $\lambda^j$ comes from cases where you take $j$ of the $\lambda$'s and $n-j$ factors that are entries of $A$.
In particular the coefficient of $\lambda^n$ in $f(\lambda)$ is $1$, 
the coefficient of $\lambda^{n-1}$ is $-\text{trace}(A)$, and the coefficient of $\lambda^k$ for $k < n-1$ is a polynomial in the entries of $A$ with every term of degree $n-k$.  Therefore either $f(1) = 1 - \text{trace}(A) + O(\|A\|^2)$ or $f(1) = -1 + \text{trace}(A) + O(\|A\|^2)$.

Comment: but why the remaining terms are $O(||A||^2)$ ?

Comment: The remaining terms include the product of $n-j \geq 2$ entries of $A$.  Note that the $i,j$ entry satisfies
$$
|A_{ij}| = |e_i^T A e_j| \leq \|e_i\|\|A e_j\| \leq \|e_i\| \|A\| \|e_j\| = \|A\| = O(\|A\|)
$$